# MacOS XAMPP Issue

Tags: php, apache, xampp, webserver, php-5.6

I am using XAMPP with PHP 5.6.35 on MacOS High Sierra.  I am trying to set up a folder which contains all my Database connection PHP classes.  That all of my other folders can gain access to.  So in my htdocs.  I would have a database directory.  My other folders at the same level would be something like blog.  In the php script for my index.php, I would have

```
require("database/dbconnect.php");
```

This would automatically pick up the database directory and the file in the database directory that I need access to.  I know in Windows, it can be done using environment variables.  What needs to be done so that I can do this structure on my mac?

Comment: What do Windows environment variables have to do with anything? If you need to pass anything in that is always an option, regardless of OS. Maybe show us some code. Also maybe worth reading about [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload)?

Comment: I know that what is used on something with Windows.  So i was wondering if something similar is available on Mac

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `require '../database/dbconnect.php';`

Comment: On Windows using Windows Environement Variables?? Hammer / Nut and totally not transportable

Comment: Still makes no sense to me, "I know that what is used on something with Windows.". Show me this code that works on Windows and I'll gladly make it work on a mac.

Comment: Where did you get those single quotes from. Are you coding with a word preocessor? That could be your problem

Comment: yes i have tried that.

Comment: show the code that is broken, not some hypothetical solution looking for a problem to solve. ps : autoload works magic, learn and code.

Comment: I know it does and it’s an older php application and it’s not an interest to the client to rewrite it.  What I am saying is broken. It works fine on windows machines on coworkers computer but does not on mine

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don‘t understand your problem. You have your htdocs folder which is your webroot. There ist your starting index.php file. You create a folder insight the htdocs folder called “database” and you can reach all files insight from the index.php with the

```
require_once "database/db.php";
```

Does this not work?
But please read some documentation about autoloading and the PSR rules. Please use autoloading with a namespace in your classes and do not put all of code insight the webroot.

Comment: My problem is that I have a directory which contain all my database php files.  What I want to do is set that file so that I can do
   `require("database/db.php")`
I want this structure for my code so in a directory like blog, i can do the above require statement without using the ../ structure in my code.

Comment: You can do it without any pain. Please post parts of your code which is not working. I also don’t know what it has to do with the OS?!?!

Comment: The part of the code that isn't working is that I am unable to pick up the directory database that is the same level as the blog directory without using the ../ in my blog/index.php file